# Two dimensional array to hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

In Ruby, given an array:

```
{"server"=>["nginx/1.1.19"], "date"=>["Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT"],"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}
```

What is the best way to convert this into a hash:

```
{"server"=>"nginx/1.1.19", "date"=>"Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT","content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Comment: What you presented as an array is already, in fact, a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a `Hash` not an `Array`

```
h = {"server"=>["nginx/1.1.19"], "date"=>["Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT"],"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}

Hash[h.map(&:flatten)]

# {"server"=>"nginx/1.1.19", "date"=>"Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT", "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do as below :

```
Hash[h.map{|k,v| [k,v[0]] }]
# => {"server"=>"nginx/1.1.19",
#     "date"=>"Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT",
#     "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"server"=>["nginx/1.1.19"], "date"=>["Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT"],"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}
hash.each{|k, v| hash[k] = v.first}
# => {"server"=>"nginx/1.1.19", "date"=>"Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT", "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Comment: I see you are leaning on the word, "convert", which is fine.  To preserve, `hash.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v), h| h[k] = v.first}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
h.map do |k, v|
  if v.size > 1
    {k => v.join("; ")}
  else
    {k => v.first}
  end
end

# => [{"server"=>"nginx/1.1.19"},  {"date"=>"Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT"},  {"content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8"}]
```

and then merge it to one hash:

```
 h2.inject({}) do |acc, el|
   acc.merge el
 end
#=> {"server"=>"nginx/1.1.19", "date"=>"Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:48:02 GMT", "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

I assumed that every value could be array of strings, if value contain only one string, go for other, easier answer.